# Why does == return true for NSNumber with same values?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I typically use `isEqualToNumber:` to check for equality of NSNumbers. The following should not work but it does, why?

```
NSNumber *number1 = @5;
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithLong:5];

if (number1 == number2)
{
    NSLog(@"Equal");
}
```

It should be checking the pointer addresses and not the actual values. Did something change in the compiler?

I am using Xcode 5.1

Comment: Because CFNumber caches them, and uses tagged pointers... Just look at the implementation: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/CFNumber.c

Comment: As an aside, if you would like to disable this caching behavior altogether (perhaps it causes issues with your code?), you can set the environment variable 'CFNumberDisableCache' to 'all' to disable caching and tagging, as outlined in `__CFNumberInitialize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are the same object. Instances of small NSNumbers are cached by their implementation, and now Objective-C actually uses tagging for NSNumbers within a certain range.

Similarly, `[@"someString" copy]` will simply return `@"someString"`. As long as the semantics are preserved correctly, the framework is free to do all sorts of things like this under the hood.

Comment: No, cocoa doesn't cache the instances. CoreFoundation does. Cocoa is the UI Toolkit.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Cocoa is an umbrella framework that includes Foundation. The UI toolkit is either AppKit or UIKit.

Comment: But cocoa doesn't include CoreFoundation, where the caching actually happens. Small, but distinct difference.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: NSNumber is a Foundation class, and that is what we're interacting with. It is toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation's CFNumber, but to say that it is not a part of Cocoa is quite inaccurate. If you are using Foundation, you will get the behavior.

Comment: But because of the toll-free bridging, none of the caching actually happens inside cocoa. It's all done in the runtime itself (for tagged pointers), or CoreFoundation. Cocoa is irrelevant.

Comment: You don't know if Cocoa includes CF or not. It is free to do so in private implementation in various places.

Comment: "Cocoa does X" is not wrong just because the code for X is in CoreFoundation. NSObject is indisputably Cocoa, but until recently it was defined in CoreFoundation.